# sas load array from table

Tags: arrays, sas, lookup

I need to load a 2d array from table to a SAS data step and then use it to perform variable transformation in another table. The array looks something like this:

- rows: initial_value 1-4
- columns: year 1-4

`1 1 2 3 
2 2 2 3 
3 4 4 4 
4 4 5 6`

So far I've hardcoded the array into sas code: 

`data example;
    array lookup {4,4} _temporary_
    1 1 2 3 
    2 2 2 3 
    3 4 4 4 
    4 4 5 6
    ;
    set source(keep=(value years));
    value_final = lookup{value, years};
run;`

How do I do the same thing without hardcoding the matrix, but rather loading a table into data step and using as array?

Comment: If you are working with matrices then you may want to look into `proc iml`.  Rick Wicklin has some great examples on his blog (http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/).  Alternatively, look into hash tables.  On a side note, you may want to describe exactly what you plan on doing transformation-wise (so people can be more helpful), or simplify your question to just how can I load a table into a multidimensional array.

Comment: thanks, this is a rather anecdoctical case - I only need the array for a simple lookup. One solution I've just come up with would be to transform the array to the form of list - value for each pair of year and initial value and then make a join. Might be answering my own question, but I'd still be curious if it's possible to load an array from a table in a data step :)

Comment: Sounds like a hash table may be the 'standard' way to go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the lookup table into a data set with years and value.  Then load that into and associative array.

```
data lookup;
   do value = 1 to 4;
      do years = 1 to 4;
         input value_final @;
         output;
         end;
      end;
   cards;
1 1 2 3 
2 2 2 3 
3 4 4 4 
4 4 5 6
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data source;
   input years value @@;
   cards;
3 2  4 1 5 0  2 2
;;;;
   run;

data example;
   if _n_ eq 1 then do;
      if 0 then set lookup;
      declare hash lookup(dataset:'lookup');
      lookup.definekey('value','years');
      lookup.definedata('value_final');
      lookup.definedone();
      end;
   set source;
   if lookup.find() ne 0 then call missing(value_final);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

You can load into array but it is a bit clunky and you have to know the dimension. And you have to check for subscript out of range which I did not do.

```
data lookup;
   do value = 1 to 4;
      do years = 1 to 4;
         input value_final @;
         output;
         end;
      end;
   cards;
1 1 2 3 
2 2 2 3 
3 4 4 4 
4 4 5 6
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data source;
   input years value @@;
   cards;
3 2  4 1 2 2
;;;;
   run;

data example;
   array lookup[4,4] _temporary_;
   if _n_ eq 1 then do;
      do while(not eof);
         set lookup end=eof;
         lookup[value,years]=value_final;
         end;
      end;
   set source;
   value_final=lookup[value,years];
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I need :) and an interesting piece of code for the lookup table. Definitely need to look up the hash tables functionality.